# Projecting two convex polyhedra onto their intersection

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, convex-optimization

Suppose we are given two convex polyhedra $\mathcal{C}_1, \mathcal{C}_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with non-empty intersection $\mathcal{C}_1 \cap \mathcal{C}_2 \neq \emptyset$.

For the orthogonal projection of a point $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ onto the intersection $\mathcal{C}_1 \cap \mathcal{C}_2$, we would in general have to solve the quadratic program
$$\textrm{argmin}_z ||x - z||_2^2 \; s.t. \; z \in \mathcal{C}_1 \cap \mathcal{C}_2 \; .
$$

Now, if we additionally know that the point to be projected is already in one of the sets, say $x \in \mathcal{C}_1$, can one use this information to solve the problem more efficiently compared to solving a full quadratic program?

Comment: Considering the case of two hyperplanes, I do not see many room for improvement.